# After pressing enter on element, tab focus is not changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a large project and need to fix some accessibility issues.

I need to navigate to a Profile icon and then to a Dropdown menu using Tab on the keyboard. If you hover over the Profile icon you can see a Dropdown menu.

To tab to the Profile icon I added tabindex="0" which worked fine however the dropdown list was not appearing.

To fix this I added an extra bit of css. I copied the existing css:

- .user .user-profile-image:hover .dropdown-menu {display: block;}

And in a new line added:

- .user .user-profile-image:focus .dropdown-menu {display: block;}

Now when you tab to the profile icon you can see the dropdown menu:

[image: dropdown menu]
-- So far so good. Unfortunately if I click tab again when I am focused on the profile icon, it does not focus on any items from the dropdown list and so I cannot select them.

To fix this I decided to allow the user to click enter on the profile icon and that would change their focus to the first element:

```
   $("#user-profile-image-click").keyup(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            alert(document.activeElement);
            $("#first-element-dropdown-list").focus();
            alert(document.activeElement);
        }
    });
```

Here the 'Account Settings' li has id="first-element-dropdown-list" and user profile icon has id="user-profile-image-click".

What's weird is when the user clicks enter they see the first alert (still focused on the span with id="user-profile-image-click" as expected and then the second alert is exactly the same. I have targeted other elements that are not part of the dropdown list over the webpage and still the focus won't change.

I don't expect you to be able to tell me what the issue is. What I need to know is how do I debug it? I have been going at it for hours. There are no console errors, the item with the id="first-element-dropdown-list" definitely exists. I am testing in chrome so the focus() should definitely work. Jquery is working fine otherwise the alerts wouldn't keep popping up.

Is there something in this large system that could be effecting my piece of code? I just want to add this as a patch on top and not change any of the underlining code. Any suggestions as to how I find out what is causing the issue?

--- ADDED ---

```
       <nav class="user clearfix">
                <div id="google_translate_element" class="google-translate-element"></div>
                <div class="user-info">
                                        <span class="user-profile-image" tabindex="0">
                        <span class="userpicture"><i class=" fa fa-user-circle-o"></i></span>
                        <span class="user-name">CA</span>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="user-profile-data">
                                <span class="userpicture"><i title="Profile icon" class=" fa fa-user-circle-o"></i></span>
                                <div class="user-name">Corp Admin</div>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="http://localhost:8888/moodle/user/view.php?id=2" title="Profile">Account Settings</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://localhost:8888/moodle/login/change_password.php" title="Change password">Change password</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://localhost:8888/moodle/login/logout.php?sesskey=4Wai1gYm3D" title="Sign Out">Sign Out</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div data-state="closed" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="dropdown menu" role="menu" class="mobile-toggler" tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
            </nav>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting tabindex on the menu items? On this question: _Is there something in this large system that could be effecting my piece of code?_ Well yes, of-course.

Comment: Yes I have added tabindex="0" to all the menu items. What I'm asking is how do I override it and make the .focus() priority? Also what kind of code would stop a .focus()?

Comment: It is unlikely the elements are in any arrangement that would allow all zeros to work. The tabindex should be sequential. Please read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

Comment: From your source: "its order is defined by the document's source order." The elements are in sequence in both the inspector and the code plus I tested with tabindex="1", tabindex="2", ect.
This isn't really the issue anyway. The issue is .focus() is not running. What could block a standard JQuery function from executing?

Comment: Event delegation. something else capturing that same event and then stopping propagation.

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with how this works in JQuery, do you know of any processes/Chrome extensions I can use to find out which event may be preventing propagation? Also is there anyway around it? Essentially force the JQuery to run regardless of event delegation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you provide your navbar html? the answer is really depends on that.

**short answer:** why your code not work. because you have css `.user-profile-image:focus{display:block}` and js `$("#first-element-dropdown-list").focus();`

when you press enter , focus change to the child element not parent anymore.

And because parent is losing focus, your dropdown will hidden because of your css.

And because your dropdown is hidden. focus will change to `undefined`.

your code is works but **looks like** not work. you can fix this using `focus()` and `blur()`.

good example: open https://getbootstrap.com/ main page. then play with the navbar (top of the page) using `tab` and `enter` or the [w3schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar_click)

Comment: I have added as much of the HTML as I am allowed to. Is there away to keep focus on the parent element while tabbing through the Children?

Answer (score 0):

So plonknimbuzz you were right, when the parent changed to display none it could no longer focus on the child elements.

To fix this I removed all the CSS related to this dropdown and converted it into the following JQuery:

```
<script>
    $('header .user .user-profile-image').hover(
      function() {
        $('header .user .user-profile-image .dropdown-menu').css('display','block');
        $('header .user .user-profile-image > .userpicture').css('display','none');
        $('header .user .user-profile-image .user-name').css('display','block');
      }, function() {
        $('header .user .user-profile-image .dropdown-menu').css('display','none');
        $('header .user .user-profile-image > .userpicture').css('display','block');
        $('header .user .user-profile-image .user-name').css('display','none');
      }
    );
    $('header .user .user-profile-image').focus(
      function() {
        $('header .user .user-profile-image .dropdown-menu').css('display','block');
        $('header .user .user-profile-image > .userpicture').css('display','none');
        $('header .user .user-profile-image .user-name').css('display','block');
      }
    );
    $('header .user .user-profile-image #signout-remove-focus').blur(
        function() {
        $('header .user .user-profile-image .dropdown-menu').css('display','none');
        $('header .user .user-profile-image > .userpicture').css('display','block');
        $('header .user .user-profile-image .user-name').css('display','none');
      }
    );
</script>
```

The **blur** section is a bit of a hack. I added a id='signout-remove-focus' to the last li in the dropdown list so once they tab past the last element, the list disappears. This was the only way keep focus on the dropdown list as I believe the webpage always runs the 'blur' or 'hover' events on the element it is leaving before it runs it on the element it is switching focus to.

The bad side to this fix is if the user starts moving their mouse while the dropdown menu is in focus it will not disappear unless the hover over it and then move the mouse off it. It's a minor bug though as it would require the end user to be using a combination of tab and mouse.

If anyone can think of a better solution I'm all ears!

Comment: yes. you are absolutely correct. we can hack your html structure using js/jquery only. and above is the result. if you meet any bug you can still hack it using jquery too. but we will no need to hack anything if you use /change your html. looks [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar_click)